# (Quick-) sorting a list of files in POSIX sh

Tags: sorting, sh, posix, quicksort

Quite often, I find myself thinking that it would be good to have a general solution that is as portable as possible, "if I ever need this on a weird or constraint machine".

I have been searching for a way to more or less efficiently sort a list of files in a directory in reverse order, using POSIX sh and tools only.

This should work with arbitrarily named files, including such with control code characters (e.g., newlines) in their name.

Comment: Just to be clear, you just want to sort the file-names according to the rule set in `LC_COLLATE` (default lexicographically) (`ls -r`)? Or do you want to sort the content of the  files (`sort -r`)? And what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Originally, sorting the file names lexicographically, like `ls -r` does if not sorting by time, yes. Parsing `ls` output is not possible if you don't want to discriminate on file names (see arbitrary names), though. The file's content is irrelevant. Eventually, I needed to iterate this sorted list and pass each element individually to a function that does something useful with it. My actual script generates a grub configuration/boot entries in a complicated manner - newest first. But *what* you do with sorted data eventually is up to the user. :)

Comment: Also, note that this question is more Q&A style. My actual intention is to share this, since there hasn't been any implementation of this publicly posted on SO yet. Hope it's helpful to other people.

Comment: Typically in POSIX environment, you could install ruby/perl/python/C compiler and do the job there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea is to process a set of files in lexicographical reverse order. As you know, you cannot parse `ls`, due to the weird filenames. Since this is POSIX, we don't have arrays. So here is a solution that might work.

Glob expressions return a list of possible filenames in lexicographical order. So you could do something like

```
for file in /path/to/dir/*; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    some_command "${file}"
done
```

If you want to reverse it, you can just do:

```
set -- /path/to/dir/*
i=$#
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do 
    eval "file=\${${i}}"; i=$((i-1));
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    some_command "$file"
done
```

**Note**: we have to use an [evil `eval`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for the evaluation of the positional variable.

**Update:** it is possible that positional variables are already in use. In this case you can do the following:

```
j=$#
set -- /path/to/dir/* "$@"
i=$(($#-$j))
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do 
    eval "file=\${${i}}"; i=$((i-1));
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue
    some_command "$file"
done
shift "$i"
```

Comment: Good points. Glob expressions must be sorted according to the collation sequence. So the first solution works fine for the "normal" order. The `for ((...))` construct (numeric C-like for loop) is a bashism though, and not portable. It would be easy to make it POSIX-compatible though by replacing it with a while loop. Setting file names to positional arguments and iterating back-to-front is a clever way of handling this.

Comment: @Ionic. There were some more issues. I think they are all resolved now.

Comment: Looks good. Can you edit it again to fix the eval line? Should be `eval "file=\${${i}}";` - otherwise it breaks for `i > 9`. I can't save my edit because the change is smaller than 6 characters...

Comment: I'll mark your solution as accepted, because it solves the initial problem in a clean, fast, elegant, short and clever way. For other cases (e.g., non-lexicographical ordering), my post provides a more generic solution that can be adapted. This way, we should be able to cover all cases with both of our algorithms. :)

Answer (score 2):

This code is fully POSIX-compliant, as far as I can tell. The only part that is not POSIX-compatible is the usage of `pwgen` for test data generation. I didn't want to go overboard on that piece, since I don't consider it part of the actual code - it's merely convenience for... testing it.

The good parts:

- it's using arrays! (Actually, it really emulates arrays in a compliant way.)
- iterative, *almost* in-place quicksort algorithm with random pivot selection. This is really an adapted version of [greybeard's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/93149) [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184645). The "*almost*" part comes from using a stack emulation to track intervals, which uses, on average, about `O(log(n))` additional space, if I'm not mistaken.
- file names can include any character (but `NUL`, which is a common problem in POSIX shell and is often disallowed by file systems anyway).
- comparison function `comp_lex_rev` can easily be swapped for a different one/modified to other behavior, e.g., if you need numerical sorting in order instead - i.e., it's modular.

The ugly parts:

- `rand()`-based random number generation, but anything else would be difficult to do portably. My initial code used to read from `/dev/urandom` and parse that data, but of course, that's not part of POSIX.
- weird, function-prefixed variable names. This is a direct consequence of POSIX sh not supporting local variables. They can be emulated (to some degree) by saving old values, using variables as you see fit and finally restoring the original values, but that really makes code even more unreadable (and error-prone, as you'd either need to have one fixed exit point in functions or duplicate the restoring functionality at every possible exit point). Prefixing variables with an unique (ahem) string works around this issue, trading readability for scopeability.
- needs direct access to the global input pseudo-array. Calling the function in a subshell and not processing the result there will just be a waste of CPU time, since the original data in the parent process won't be changed. That's a general issue in shell scripting, but probably worth mentioning.
- integers are tricky. Originally, I explicitly limited the random number fetching part to `2^16 - 1`, since that's the smallest guaranteed integer size - which probably means that the shell must support it too, as a minimum. However, enforcing a limit there doesn't make sense. Instead, I opted for some sort of overflow detection while generating the input array. Just keep in mind that the maximum integer size usable in the shell is implementation-specific with a hard lower bound.
- being shell-based, it's pretty slow compared to a direct binary implementation in, e.g., C. `expr` is notorious for being slow and forking out to other programs makes a shell script even slower. As an anecdote, I was able to cut down on the processing time in a zsh script considerably by replacing `grep` and `sed` calls with zsh-internal regular expression handling. Likewise, this point is more a general issue with shell scripting and has nothing to do with my code, but it's also good to keep it in mind.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#set -x

comp_lex_rev () {
  comp_lex_rev_a="${1:?'No lhs passed to comp_lex_rev(), this is invalid.'}"
  comp_lex_rev_b="${2:?'No rhs passed to comp_lex_rev(), this is invalid.'}"

  comp_lex_rev_expr_out="$('expr' "x${comp_lex_rev_a}" '>' "x${comp_lex_rev_b}")"
  if [ '1' -eq "${comp_lex_rev_expr_out}" ]; then
    return '0'
  else
    return '1'
  fi
}

get_rand () {
  get_rand_min="${1:?'No minimum value passed to get_rand(), this is invalid.'}"
  get_rand_max="${2:?'No maximum value passed to get_rand(), this is invalid.'}"

  # Minimum value must be positive.
  if [ '0' -gt "${get_rand_min}" ]; then
    return '1'
  fi

  # Max > min doesn't make sense... (we could just swap them here, but meh.)
  if [ "${get_rand_min}" -gt "${get_rand_max}" ]; then
    return '1'
  fi

  # Not much to do if both are the same value.
  if [ "${get_rand_min}" -eq "${get_rand_max}" ]; then
    'printf' '%s\n' "${get_rand_min}"
    return '0'
  fi

  # Just be extra careful.
  get_rand_out=''
  while [ -z "${get_rand_out}" ] || [ "${get_rand_min}" -gt "${get_rand_out}" ] || [ "${get_rand_max}" -lt "${get_rand_out}" ]; do
    get_rand_out="$('awk' '
      BEGIN {
        srand ();
        printf ("%u", (rand () * (('"${get_rand_max}"' - '"${get_rand_min}"') + 1)) + '"${get_rand_min}"');
      }')"
  done

  'printf' '%s\n' "${get_rand_out}"
}

qsort () {
  qsort_arr="${1:?'No array base passed to qsort(), this is invalid.'}"
  qsort_n="${2:?'No array length passed to qsort(), this is invalid.'}"

  if [ '2' -gt "${qsort_n}" ]; then
    # One or zero elements are always sorted.
    return '0'
  fi

  qsort_range_0='0'
  qsort_range_1="$((${qsort_n} - 1))"
  qsort_range_n='2'
  # Must have at least one pair entry in the range "stack".
  while [ '1' -lt "${qsort_range_n}" ]; do
    qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} - 1))"
    eval 'qsort_high="${qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'}"'
    qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} - 1))"
    eval 'qsort_low="${qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'}"'

    qsort_cur_i="${qsort_low}"
    qsort_pivot_i="$('get_rand' "${qsort_low}" "${qsort_high}")"
    if [ '0' -ne "${?}" ]; then
      # Fetching random value failed, fall back to rightmost element.
      qsort_pivot_i="${qsort_high}"
    fi

    eval 'qsort_pivot="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'}"'

    # Move pivot up if it isn't already.
    if [ "${qsort_high}" != "${qsort_pivot_i}" ]; then
      eval "${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_high}"'}"'
      eval "${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_high}"'="${qsort_pivot}"'
      qsort_pivot_i="${qsort_high}"
    fi

    eval 'qsort_cur="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_cur_i}"'}"'
    while [ "${qsort_pivot_i}" -gt "${qsort_cur_i}" ]; do
      if 'comp_lex_rev' "${qsort_cur}" "${qsort_pivot}"; then
        qsort_cur_i="$((${qsort_cur_i} + 1))"
        eval 'qsort_cur="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_cur_i}"'}"'
      else
        eval "${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'="${qsort_cur}"'
        qsort_pivot_i="$((${qsort_pivot_i} - 1))"
        eval "${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_cur_i}"'="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'}"'
        eval 'qsort_cur="${'"${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'}"'
      fi
    done
    eval "${qsort_arr}"'_'"${qsort_pivot_i}"'="${qsort_pivot}"'

    qsort_lhs_size="$((${qsort_pivot_i} - ${qsort_low}))"
    qsort_rhs_size="$((${qsort_high} - ${qsort_pivot_i}))"
    if [ "${qsort_lhs_size}" -le "${qsort_rhs_size}" ]; then
      if [ '1' -lt "${qsort_lhs_size}" ]; then
        eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="$((${qsort_pivot_i} + 1))"'
        qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
        eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="${qsort_high}"'
        qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"

        eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="${qsort_low}"'
        qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
        eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="$((${qsort_pivot_i} - 1))"'
        qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
      fi
    else
      eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="${qsort_low}"'
      qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
      eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="$((${qsort_pivot_i} - 1))"'
      qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
    fi

    if [ '1' -lt "${qsort_rhs_size}" ]; then
      eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="$((${qsort_pivot_i} + 1))"'
      qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
      eval 'qsort_range_'"${qsort_range_n}"'="${qsort_high}"'
      qsort_range_n="$((${qsort_range_n} + 1))"
    fi
  done
}

print_arr () {
  print_arr_arr="${1:?'No array base passed to print_arr(), this is invalid.'}"
  print_arr_n="${2:?'No array length passed to print_arr(), this is invalid.'}"

  print_arr_i='0'
  while [ "${print_arr_n}" -gt "${print_arr_i}" ]; do
    if [ '0' -ne "${print_arr_i}" ]; then
      'printf' '===\n'
    fi
    eval "'"'printf'"'"' '"'"'%s\n'"'"' "${'"${print_arr_arr}"'_'"${print_arr_i}"'}"'
    print_arr_i="$((${print_arr_i} + 1))"
  done
}

generate_testdata () {
  generate_testdata_dir="${1:?'No testdata directory passed to generate_testdata(), this is invalid.'}"

  generate_testdata_i='0'
  generate_testdata_n='100'
  (
    'mkdir' "${generate_testdata_dir}"
    'cd' "${generate_testdata_dir}"
    while [ "${generate_testdata_n}" -gt "${generate_testdata_i}" ]; do
      # We'll map the first underscore character to a space character and
      # ditto for right curly bracket vs. newline since pwgen generates no
      # such characters by default.
      ':' > "$('pwgen' '-s' '-y' '-c' '-n' '-r' '/' '100' '1' | 'sed' '-e' 's#_# #' '-e' 's#}#\
#')"
      generate_testdata_i="$((${generate_testdata_i} + 1))"
    done
  )
}

main () {
  main_testdir='testdata'
  if [ ! -d "${main_testdir}" ]; then
    'generate_testdata' "${main_testdir}"
  fi

  main_cur_file=''
  main_flist_n='0'
  main_flist_old_n="${main_flist_n}"
  for main_cur_file in "${main_testdir}"/*; do
    if [ -f "${main_cur_file}" ]; then
      eval 'main_flist_'"${main_flist_n}"'="${main_cur_file}"'
      main_flist_n="$((${main_flist_n} + 1))"

      if [ "${main_flist_old_n}" -ge "${main_flist_n}" ]; then
        # Overflow (or... none-flow?), stop working.
        'printf' 'Too many files to handle, aborting.\n' >&'2'
        return '1'
      else
        main_flist_old_n="${main_flist_n}"
      fi
    fi
  done

  # Sort, in reverse order.
  'qsort' 'main_flist' "${main_flist_n}"

  # And finally print out.
  'print_arr' 'main_flist' "${main_flist_n}"

  # In GNU terms,
  # 'find' "${main_testdir}" '-type' 'f' '-print0' | 'sort' '-rz' | 'sed' '-e' 's#\x0#\n===\n#g'
  # should return about the same data, only with an additional separator at the end.
}

# Actual main code.
'main'
```